# MongoDb query - match child array against multiple items in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a record like this

```
{
  "formAnswers": {
    "id": 1,
    "entries": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "favoriteColor": "red",
      },
      {
        "name": "Kevin",
        "favoriteColor": "green",
      },
      {
        "name": "Susan",
        "favoriteColor": "blue",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to match this record based on the fact it has two entries, one with favoriteColor: "red" and another with favoriteColor: "green" - both at the same time.

I was thinking something like this would work, but it does not...

```
{
  "formAnswers.entries": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$all": ["red", "green"]
    }
  }
}
```

If I was looking for "red" and "purple" it should not match, because there are no entries with favoriteColor: "purple".  The fact that the child array is under another property, "formAnswers", is killing me.  I can get it to work without that, but I need the query to match the document as described.  That extra level of indirection is stressing my very limited mongo query knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `$elemMatch` (since you're just querying on a single field), and add `.favoriteColor` to the field identifier in the query (since you aren't querying on the full subdocument):

```
db.collection.find({
  "formAnswers.entries.favoriteColor": {
    "$all": [
      "red",
      "green"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wpoki_JxP55)